# How to customize vertical panel in cinnamon menu?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

[image]

I want to edit highlited area: for example, change firefox with chromium or remove any item. Menu editor can change only right part of menu, changing default application has no effect on this panel.

Comment: Similar question here: http://askubuntu.com/q/302293/25656

Comment: Something wrong with it?

Comment: Yes, cross-posting is [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/203101) on the SE network. One of your questions will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is click and drag. In the image below, I have selected Firefox and am in the process of moving it down a few places:

[image]

To remove an icon just drag it away and to add one navigate to it in the menu and drag it onto the right hand side.